# AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android

The bug report is as follow:

```
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.settings, PID: 12975
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.android.settings.accessibility.ToggleColorInversionPreferenceFragment$3)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2116)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1886)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:978)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1629)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1047)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:120)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1740)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1720)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:619)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1907)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1813)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:978)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1629)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4604)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8049)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.android.settings.accessibility.ToggleColorInversionPreferenceFragment
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2111)
01-12 06:22:27.481 1000 12975 12975 E AndroidRuntime: ... 23 more
```

The question is that there is nothing about Bean. All the putInt() and getInt() are android system based class.

```
        private static final String ENABLED = Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_DISPLAY_INVERSION_ENABLED;
        ...
        @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
        public @interface State {
            int OFF = 0;
            int ON = 1;
        }

        ...

        final boolean enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                      settingsSecureKey, State.OFF) == State.ON;
        ...
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), ENABLED, checked ? ON : OFF);
```

And the bug report didn't provide an actual line number where this bug happened. I am pretty confused about this. Hope any one reply me :)

Comment: The date of the bug report is 01-12. Are you sure you are looking for the correct bug report? The date is correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to fix this so I have put it away and went fixing other bugs. Just remembered that this one hasn't been fixed yet today :(